# Передача необязательного параметра в OData контроллер

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, передача-параметров

Всем доброго времени суток!
Есть метод в контроллере:

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("Sms(PhoneNumber={key}, StartDate={StartDate})/Sms.SendSmsCode")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SendSmsCode([FromODataUri] string key, bool param=false)
```

Если обращаюсь к нему вот так -
/Sms(PhoneNumber='123456789',StartDate=1900-01-01)/Sms.SendSmsCode?param=true

получаю ошибку:
{
"error":{
"code":"","message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '/Sms(PhoneNumber='123456789',StartDate=1900-01-01)/Sms.SendSmsCode?param=true'.","innererror":{
"message":"No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/action'.","type":"","stacktrace":""
}
}
}

Если обращаюсь без указания ?param=true - ошибки нет и все работает.

Помогите понять в чем ошибка и как передать параметр?

Comment: OData, не  OData... это дело десятое. Есть такая тема в asp.net - называется роутинг/маршрутизация и в ней плохо разобрались. Покажите [объявления ваших эндпойнтов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1), которые вы сделали в Startup.cs

Comment: В startup эндпойнты не определялись никакие.

Comment: Так не бывает. Значит, были вызовы методов расширения, которые устанавливают какие-то дефолтные значения. Поэтому я бы очень рекомендовал указать какая у вас версия asp.net core - ибо их код разный и умолчания разные, да и просто привести код Startup.cs

Comment: решил проблему так: public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SendSmsCode([FromODataUri] string key, [FromUri] bool param=false)

Comment: Лучше оформите это ответом.

Answer (score 1):

решил проблему так:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SendSmsCode([FromODataUri] string key, [FromUri] bool param=false)
```